# Greasemonkey script compilation to add-on

Tags: firefox, compiler-construction, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

What happens to the configuration values that are used inside a GM script with GM_setvalue and GM_getvalue when the script is compiled into an add-on? Where are they stored if Greasemonkey is not already installed on the computer?
I know that as a GM script, you can access its values on the computer by navigating to about:config. But what if there is no GM installed after compilation to an add-on?

Answer (score 0):

Values can be stored either in localStorage or preferences. In case of Arantius' I think it uses preferences - should be under the add-on's root key, as visible from `this.setValue=function(prefName, value)` in http://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler.phps under `function \$shortname_PrefManager()`, but I may be wrong.

According to the source, should be under name "script" + a unique ID generated by PHP, concatenated together.

Comment: Are you sure?  I don't think this is the case with GM scripts that are "compiled" into add-ons by Arantius' tool -- which is still the only GM compiler, I believe.

Comment: In his compiler, he uses preferences - look in http://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler.phps for `function \$shortname_PrefManager() {`, it contains the `setValue` and `getValue` code.

Comment: "Preferences" in Firefox are accessible via `about:config`.  So the "compiled" extension would work exactly the same as a regular GM script.  However, I've yet to analyze that code well enough to be sure he hasn't mapped "Preferences" to something else (although I doubt it).

Comment: Exactly the same, but under another root key.

Comment: Well, then.  Wouldn't that make this answer currently wrong?  FF's preferences are neither localStorage nor the compiler's preferences.